# multiple li elements but show a specific div per element not all jquery

Tags: jquery, toggle, html-lists

I've got a list which i want to have a share/delete showing on hover

```
<ul class="folder-items">

  <li><a href="">This</a></li>
    <div class="folder-hover"><a href="">share</a><a href="">delete</a></div>

   <li><a href="">That</a></li>
    <div class="folder-hover"><a href="">share</a><a href="">delete</a></div>

  <li><a href="">Other</a></li>
    <div class="folder-hover"><a href="">share</a><a href="">delete</a></div>

</ul>
```

but it is targeting all of the .folder-hover when I hover over the .folder-items a

How do I get it so it only toggles the div on that specific li element

my current jquery is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.folder-items a').hover(function(){
     $('.file-hover').toggle();
   });
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your markup is invalid (`div` cannot be a direct child of `ul`). If you fix that, you can use [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) to select the appropriate `folder-hover`:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="folder-items">

  <li><a href="">This</a>
    <div class="folder-hover"><a href="">share</a><a href="">delete</a></div>
  </li>

   <li><a href="">That</a>
    <div class="folder-hover"><a href="">share</a><a href="">delete</a></div>
   </li>

  <li><a href="">Other</a>
    <div class="folder-hover"><a href="">share</a><a href="">delete</a></div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$('.folder-items a').hover(function(){
   $(this).siblings('.folder-hover').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$(this).parent().next('div.folder-hover').toggle();
```

The `parent()` call will bring you up to the `<li>` and the next grab the next sibling matching the selector which is the `div`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rNcrk/